# Media Query Replacing Another Media Query

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask for help regarding the Media Queries. I am having trouble since with the media query. The CSS I wrote for the Ipad Air (4th Generation) Viewport overrides/overlays the Ipad Viewport. When I switched to Ipad responsive design, it responds to the Ipad Air CSS I wrote not the Ipad viewport CSS itself. Hoping for a help! Thank you.

```css
    /* @media only for Tablet View - Portrait (Ipad) */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width: 768px) 
    and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
    and (orientation: portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {


    .johncanero {
      padding: 50px 0px 0px 295px;
      height: 170px;
      width: 170px;
    }
    
    }


    /* @media only for Tablet View - Landscape (Ipad) */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width: 768px) 
    and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
    and (orientation: landscape) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

    
    .johncanero {
     padding: 50px 0px 0px 420px;
     height: 170px;
     width: 170px;
    }


    }




     /* @media only for Tablet View - Portrait (Ipad Air 4th Generation) */
     @media only screen 
     and (min-device-width: 820px) 
     and (max-device-width: 1180px) 
     and (orientation: portrait) 
     and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  
    
    .johncanero {
     padding: 50px 0px 0px 310px;
     height: 190px;
     width: 190px;
     }

     }




    /* @media only for Tablet View - Landscape (Ipad Air 4th Generation) */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width: 820px) 
    and (max-device-width: 1180px) 
    and (orientation: landscape) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

    
    
    .johncanero {
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 500px;
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
    }


    }
```

Devtools:
[image: Google Chrome Development Tools - Inspect]

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. You should never design media queries for specific devices, you would probably be fine with base mobile styles and add in complexity with min-width queries